# ASP.NET CORE web app reloads the same page after logging in

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, asp.net-core-2.0, razor-pages

I have authenticated my **ASP.NET CORE 2.0 RAZOR PAGES** template web app with **Azure AD B2C** and I can succesfully login to my app, but after login app takes me to the homepage again and only the name at top right changes with sign out option appearing.

I want to ask how can I change the content/ data of my homepage, based on that the user has logged in so I can provide them data according to their profile.?

Answer (score 1):

[See this sample project.](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnetcore-webapp/blob/master/WebApp-OpenIDConnect-DotNet/Views/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml#LC4)

```html
@if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Session" asp-action="EditProfile">Hello @User.Identity.Name!</a></li>
        <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Session" asp-action="SignOut">Sign out</a></li>
    </ul>
}
```

Comment: I can see that but as I said they are changing only one line in that if and else, I need to change whole page. How can I do that? maybe injecting a partial view? maybe I can have 2 partial views one can appear in sign out mode and one can appear in sign in mode, is that possible?

Comment: Why does it have to be the same home page? Can you not just redirect the user to another page after sign in?

Comment: I am not sure how exactly to do that because this conditional authentication check is also happening in a partial login view

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Model ( like UserProfileModel.cs)  and then pass it to the Home Page. And in the controller part you can make up this class, fill in all details and return View("Page.cshtml", model)